# How to create a folder and a folder inside a folder using REST/JSOM/Flow in a Custom List (Not a library)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, jsom

The requirement is:

When an item is created in a custom list, a folder should be created with the same name as Title of the item and the item should be placed inside the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by creating SharePoint designer workflow.

Create SharePoint 2010 platform workflow on the list like the following(choose start workflow automatically when an item is created):

1.create folder with same name as Title of the item.

Add "Create List Item" action.

select current list.

Add Content type ID > select folder, Title > select current item:Title.

2.copy the list item to the folder.

Add the "Create List Item" action.

select current list.

Add Content type ID > select item, Title > select current item:Title, additionally, set the field "Folder" to the name of the folder where the new item should be placed in.

3.Afterwards delete the current item, so only the new one stays present.

[image]

If you want to use SharePoint 2013 platform workflow, refer to the following article:

https://mariagraziamerlo.com/2016/02/13/how-to-create-a-list-item-inside-a-folder-using-a-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article: [Microsoft Flow – How to move SharePoint Online list items to folders](https://dynamics365society.uk/archives/microsoft-flow-how-to-move-sharepoint-online-list-items-to-folders/). This is approach identical to @Lisa Chen's one, but implemented via MS Flow. (This is an option according to your question)

You also may attach Remote Event Receiver (RER) to the list, or subscribe web hook. But this is not REST/JSOM/Flow

Using JavaScript (REST) for this purpose is not reliable, because you will depend on client side scripts which could has uncaught exception above code you inject so your solution might not be triggered at all. I would not recomend it.

Comment: Hi Topa3b, I have already tried this solution. I get an error as:

Failed to verify the existence of destination location at 'https://ralphlauren.sharepoint.com/sites/rl-lpp-dev/Lists/CustomList/ItemcreatedfromCode1' due to error 'The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)'.
clientRequestId: b3a43858-711a-4f01-ad70-389006bb0b7f
serviceRequestId: 67afe09e-20b3-8000-8c8f-06a68f89fc65

Comment: Have you tried the method i offered?